# Is there any way to execute a JRuby script within my Java application for Android?

Tags: java, android, jruby

I want to run a JRuby script in my Java application in Android.

- `javax.script` is not included in Android. You can try to import the package manually, but when you try to obtain the JRuby engine, it returns null.
- Apache BSF can't load the engine either. You get an error related to "privileged exception: cannot load class file" - I imagine that Android doesn't allow this sort of loading, so you can't dynamically load JRuby with BSF.
- [SL4A](https://github.com/damonkohler/sl4a) doesn't make any sense at all. Besides the fact that they don't have clear instructions on how to use it for running JRuby, the last time it was updated was like 4 years ago.
- Ruboto is used for writing Android applications with Ruby. That's not what I want. I just want to run a Ruby snippet in my Java application.

Is there **any** way you can run JRuby scripts in a Java application in Android? Are there clear instructions anywhere?

Comment: How do you expect that to work?  Ruby isn't installed on the phone, so what would be running the script?  You might be able to get it to work if you're talking a rooted phone, but that would be about it.

Comment: I think https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/JRubyAndJavaCodeExamples#Java_calling_JRuby in the !useBSF branch is roughly what https://code.google.com/p/jruby-for-android/ ("An Android application that provides a JRuby scripting environment, including an IRB shell, source code editor and script manager.") does.

Comment: @zapl, thanks for the link, however it is still unable to find `org.jruby.javasupport.bsf.JRubyEngine` - yet I know it is there because it DOES work for Desktop. But not for Android.

Comment: @GabeSechan well I don't have Ruby installed in my computer either, and yet I can use JRuby with BSF. The same should occur with Android, I guess? You don't need Ruby installed.

Comment: @Voldemort not the `if (useBSF) {` part, the `else` part, `Ruby runtime = Ruby.getDefaultInstance()` - the only thing you should need for that is to include the jruby jar in your app. - Android is indeed much different when it comes to all those extensions provided via service locators. Lots of things come standard with the oracle JRE, pretty much nothing is included in Android. If it works on desktop means nothing to android.

Comment: @zapl I see, but now it's even more puzzling: `Ruby.getDefaultInstance()` will report `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jruby.Ruby` despite the fact that I do have JRuby in my build path.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you can use the --java flag with jrubyc to generate java source code from jruby code.

If you don't have an absolute requirement to retain the jruby script at runtime, I'd do that, and then put the java code into the Android app.

Of course, you'll still need the jruby jar file in your Android app.

See https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/GeneratingJavaClasses#user-content-generating-java-classes-ahead-of-time

Comment: I made a Ruby script with an empty class. Converted it to Java. If you instantiate the class, it will say `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.company.joel.EmptyClass` in Android. Works fine in Desktop. I don't understand what's the issue with Android: I have JRuby in the build path, and even converted the script to a Java class.